# Flutter Keyboard listen on hide and show

Tags: flutter

How can I listen whether the keyboard is showing up or hiding?

I tried this example
[How to listen to keyboard on screen Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47823767/how-to-listen-to-keyboard-on-screen-flutter)

```
 void _listener(){
    if(_myNode.hasFocus){
      // keyboard appeared 
    }else{
      // keyboard dismissed
    }
}

FocusNode _myNode = new FocusNode()..addListener(_listner);

TextField _myTextField = new TextField(
        focusNode: _mynNode,
        ...
        ...
    );
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work. Any ideas how it could be possible to listen to the keyboard change?

It seems like it works when I press "Done" on the keyboard. But if i press back on my phone it won't go to "keyboard dismissed" because the focus still exists.. Any help?

Comment: can confirm this doesn't work for me on `TextFormFields` also

Comment: maybe detect the 'backButton' also using `onPop`

Answer (score 29):

### KeyboardVisibilityBuilder

Listening for keyboard show/hide events can be achieved with `WidgetsBindingObserver` mixin. I prepared `KeyboardVisibilityBuilder` widget that handles the behavior for you. The usage is quite similar to `AnimatedBuilder`:

```dart
return KeyboardVisibilityBuilder(
  builder: (context, child, isKeyboardVisible) {
    if (isKeyboardVisible) {
      // build layout for visible keyboard
    } else {
      // build layout for invisible keyboard
    }
  },
  child: child, // this widget goes to the builder's child property. Made for better performance.
);
```

`KeyboardVisibilityBuilder` implementation:

```dart
/// Calls `builder` on keyboard close/open.
/// https://stackoverflow.com/a/63241409/1321917
class KeyboardVisibilityBuilder extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final Widget Function(
    BuildContext context,
    Widget child,
    bool isKeyboardVisible,
  ) builder;

  const KeyboardVisibilityBuilder({
    Key key,
    this.child,
    @required this.builder,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _KeyboardVisibilityBuilderState createState() => _KeyboardVisibilityBuilderState();
}

class _KeyboardVisibilityBuilderState extends State<KeyboardVisibilityBuilder>
    with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  var _isKeyboardVisible = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeMetrics() {
    final bottomInset = WidgetsBinding.instance.window.viewInsets.bottom;
    final newValue = bottomInset > 0.0;
    if (newValue != _isKeyboardVisible) {
      setState(() {
        _isKeyboardVisible = newValue;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => widget.builder(
        context,
        widget.child,
        _isKeyboardVisible,
      );
}
```

Comment: Using mixin is a good idea, as we can also use it with provider

Comment: I use this to validate input fields whenever the keyboard is closed, instead of when the Apply button is pressed

Comment: Also we can give a void Function(bool isKeyboardOpened)? onKeyboardVisibilityChange; parameter to KeyboardVisibilityBuilder widget and, with this parameter, we can can it on didChangeMetrics function, like; widget.onKeyboardStatusChange?.call(newValue); with this way, we can give a function to widget for update different things with this parameter.

in this way we can notify some other things based keyboards visibility.

Comment: As far as I understand it, `viewInsets.bottom == 0` does not necessarily imply that the keyboard is closed. Some non-keyboard inset could be added to the bottom, now or in some future version of Flutter, and this would break. (e.g. think of how `SafeArea` was added to avoid the camera notch on the top of phones.)

Comment: `WidgetsBinding.instance.window` is getting deprecated, use `WidgetsBinding.instance.platformDispatcher.views.first.viewInsets.bottom`

Answer (score 11):

Not sure how reliable this is, but there's this property on [`MediaQueryData`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/MediaQueryData-class.html):

```
  /// The number of physical pixels on each side of the display rectangle into
  /// which the application can render, but over which the operating system
  /// will likely place system UI, such as the keyboard, that fully obscures
  /// any content.
  final EdgeInsets viewInsets;
```

Checking if `viewInsets.vertical` is greater than zero in the `build()` method gave me correct results:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    bool isKeyboardShowing = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.vertical > 0;

    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(isKeyboardShowing ? 'YES!' : 'NO!'),
            TextField(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

It's probably a good idea to combine this with other checks (e.g. input focus), to avoid false positives.

Comment: Do phones with notches give a false positive here?

Comment: Notches don't affect viewInsets, as the MediaQueryData page explains. Notches would be included in `.padding` and `.viewPadding`. That said, you probably should be using `.bottom`, not `.vertical`. The latter adds any top offset representing top area completely obscured by the system. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQueryData/viewInsets.html also states: ```When a mobile device's keyboard is visible viewInsets.bottom corresponds to the top of the keyboard.```.

Answer (score 8):

There is a package which mets your requirement completely. Please check that: [flutter_keyboard_visibility](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_keyboard_visibility)

In there, by using StreamSubscription, you can listen whether the keyboard becomes goes up/down and react based on that.

Answer (score 7):

what I need is a listener so I convert **Andrey Gordeev** code to

```
    import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class KeyboardVisibilityListener extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final void Function(
    bool isKeyboardVisible,
  ) listener;

  const KeyboardVisibilityListener({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
    required this.listener,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _KeyboardVisibilityListenerState createState() =>
      _KeyboardVisibilityListenerState();
}

class _KeyboardVisibilityListenerState extends State<KeyboardVisibilityListener>
    with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  var _isKeyboardVisible = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeMetrics() {
    final bottomInset = WidgetsBinding.instance!.window.viewInsets.bottom;
    final newValue = bottomInset > 0.0;
    if (newValue != _isKeyboardVisible) {
      _isKeyboardVisible = newValue;
      widget.listener(_isKeyboardVisible);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => widget.child;
}
```

and
I used it to unfocus the input field when hiding the keyboard

```
home: KeyboardVisibilityListener(
        listener: (isKeyboardVisible) {
          if (!isKeyboardVisible) {
            FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
          }
        },
        child: Scaffold(
          key: scaffoldKey,
          body: layoutp.currentItem.page,
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: now prefer to use this line instead 
      onTapOutside: (_) => FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus(),

Answer (score 3):

```
if (MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom > 0.0) {
   // keyboard on the screen
}
```

Simple explanation: **MediaQuery** to learn the size of the current media. This class use as **MediaQueryData media = MediaQuery.of(context);**. If any view appears on the screen **MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets**give some value of the height of that view. As keyboard appears from the bottom on the screen so I use **MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom** and this gives me the height of the keyboard taken on my screen. When the keyboard doesn't appear this value is 0.And this solution definitely works.

Comment: Ans edited. I think now everyone could learn something. @NicoHaase

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library
[keyboard_visibility_pro](https://pub.dev/packages/keyboard_visibility_pro)

```
KeyboardVisibility(
      // it will notify
        onChanged: (bool visible) {
          print(visible);
        },
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: const <Widget>[TextField()],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: For me keyboard_visibility_pro worked, when i wanted to subscribe to keypad visibility changes. flutter_keyboard_visibility did not work in subscribing to changes.

Answer (score 0):

Did you pick up the spelling mistake?

```
FocusNode _myNode = new FocusNode()..addListener(_listner);
```

Should be:

```
FocusNode _myNode = new FocusNode()..addListener(_listener);
```

Answer (score 0):

A widget that calls a callback whenever the user presses or releases a key on a keyboard.

A RawKeyboardListener is useful for listening to raw key events and hardware buttons that are represented as keys. Typically used by games and other apps that use keyboards for purposes other than text entry.

For text entry, consider using a EditableText, which integrates with on-screen keyboards and input method editors (IMEs).

```
const RawKeyboardListener({
Key key,
@required FocusNode focusNode,
@required ValueChanged<RawKeyEvent> onKey,
@required Widget child
})
```

Creates a widget that receives raw keyboard events.

For text entry, consider using a EditableText, which integrates with on-screen keyboards and input method editors (IMEs).

**Implementation**

```
  const RawKeyboardListener({
  Key key,
  @required this.focusNode,
  @required this.onKey,
  @required this.child,
}) : assert(focusNode != null),
     assert(child != null),
     super(key: key);
```

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023, some of the answers have become somewhat outdated.

A simple way to check for the keyboard being open and conditionally closing it if so is as follows:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void dismissKeyboard(BuildContext context) {
  if (View.of(context).viewInsets.bottom > 0.0) {
    FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
    if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
      currentFocus.unfocus();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class KeyboardVisibility extends StatefulWidget {
  const KeyboardVisibility (
      {super.key});
  @override
  State<KeyboardVisibility > createState() => _KeyboardVisibilityState();
}

class _KeyboardVisibilityState extends State<KeyboardVisibility> {
  late FocusNode myFocusNode;

  @override
  void initState() {
    myFocusNode = FocusNode();
    //add listener to focusNode so that it will get triggered whenever it     changes focus
    myFocusNode.addListener(() {
      handleKeyboardFocusChange();
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    myFocusNode.removeListener(() {
      handleKeyboardFocusChange;
    });
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      focusNode:myFocusNode
    );
    void handleKeyboardFocusChange(){
      if(myFocusNode.hasFocus){
      }else{
      }
    }

  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).