# Android Keyboard causes Status Bar to reappear

Tags: dart, flutter, android-softkeyboard, android-statusbar

I need to hide the Android Status bar in my app so i am using the following code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

main() {
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            body: Center(child: TextField()), backgroundColor: Colors.orange));
  }
}
```

I have a `textfield` in the screen so whenever the Android Keyboard opens the status bar reappears.
I have tried with multiple Android devices and i am getting the same bug.

Is this really a bug in the framework or am i doing something wrong?

I have attached a short video link below to show the bug

https://drive.google.com/file/d/19qs5Rsrfc_G1oN5kbxgKvYQAXpTr8RZx/view?usp=sharing

I have not tested in `iOS`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please share some code. I tried adding `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);` in `initState()` and I have a text field, It is working fine.

Comment: I have added code in the question, please have a look

Comment: Check on a real device

Comment: Checked your code on real device. Working fine for me. Sharing video to show

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZfBMNXYEnXZL_zALiMEVBZSrPDHxlHVM/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: which device are you using and android version. I am using Redmi with Android Marshmallow

Comment: I am using MiA1 - Android Version 9. You said you tried on multiple devices right? Which ones?

Comment: I also tried on Redmi - Lollipop, Coolpad - Marshmallow

Comment: I guess then the issue is because of Android's Fragmentation

Answer (score 2):

What I did is after the Keyboard was shown, delay for 2 (the doc says one) seconds and then call `setEnabledSystemUIOverlays` again.

```
Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2)).then((value) => SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]));
```

According to: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/SystemChrome/setEnabledSystemUIOverlays.html

> when the keyboard becomes visible, it will enable the navigation bar and status bar system UI overlays. When the keyboard is closed, Android will not restore the previous UI visibility settings, and the UI visibility cannot be changed until 1 second after the keyboard is closed to prevent malware locking users from navigation buttons.

> To regain "fullscreen" after text entry, the UI overlays should be set again after a delay of 1 second. This can be achieved through restoreSystemUIOverlays or calling this again. Otherwise, the original UI overlay settings will be automatically restored only when the application loses and regains focus.

Answer (score 0):

From your code here :

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
```

you should change `setEnabledSystemUIOverlays` which is now deprecated to :

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersiveSticky)
      .then((value) {
    runApp(MyApp());
  });
}
```

What I understand from you're question is that you think this is a bug in Flutter but to my understanding of Flutter documents this is a normal behavior that is intended whenever keyboard is shown, Apparently

> This is to prevent malware from permanently hiding navigation buttons
> [source](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/SystemChrome/restoreSystemUIOverlays.html)

I do not know how to override that but to solve you're problem you should use `SystemChrome.restoreSystemUIOverlays();` after you are done with the keyboard input.

---

This should be the end of my answer.

But to those who do not know how to do it you need to check the condition if the keyboard is open or not, you could use `WidgetsBinding.instance.window.viewInsets.bottom` , answered by [Deepak Raj](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63455075)

### OR you could use:
KeyboardVisibilityBuilder

By [Andrey Gordeev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1321917/andrey-gordeev) [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63241360)

```
KeyboardVisibilityBuilder(
    builder: (context, child, isKeyboardVisible) {
      if (isKeyboardVisible) {
        // when keyboard is visible

      } else {
        // when keyboard is invisible
        SystemChrome.restoreSystemUIOverlays();
      }
      return child;
    },
    child: TextField(),
  )
```

Here is the result:

[image: Result]