# Flutter: Detect keyboard open and close

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a `BottomNavigationBar` at the upper-most level of my application. I want to detect keyboard open and close basically anywhere in the app/subtree, so I can show and hide the `BottomNavigationBar` whenever the keyboard is visible.

This is a general issue and may not be directly related to the `BottomNavigationBar`. In other words, abstract from the `BottomNavigationBar` :-)

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_keyboard_visibility/install
Found this plugin.

Comment: You could use this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/76369015/9142353

Answer (score 111):

To check for keyboard visibility, just check for the [`viewInsets`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQueryData/viewInsets.html) property anywhere in the widget tree. The keyboard is hidden when `viewInsets.bottom` is equal to zero.

You can check for the `viewInsets` with `MediaQuery` like:

```
MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom
```

Comment: That's a bad practice. ViewInset is not specific to keyboard. I'd suggest to use platform_channel to directly call native API that tells if the keyboard is visible or not.

Comment: @Darky But that is the only way you can do it. Observe window size to infer if keyboard is visible, there is no direct method as far as I know. You can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745988/how-do-i-detect-if-software-keyboard-is-visible-on-android-device). If I'm wrong do correct me.

Comment: And more over I thought implementing a platform_channel is unnecessary here as the `viewInsets` are already being updated with respect to events.

Comment: But ViewInset is not "isKeyboardVisible". If you have a floating keyboard, it'll be visible with a ViewInset of 0 for example

Comment: That's true, but ideally `isKeyboardVisible` = viewInsets.bottom > 200px or not equal to zero ideally. There no other way that you can tell if keyboard is visible.

Comment: I think floating keyboard scenario is inevitable. I find no docs or reference to detect a floating keyboard. If can, do educate me. :)

Comment: Platform_channel should make things slightly better. IOS (and most likely fushia) have some events on keyboard visibility. The problem is Android I guess. But then for Android only you could use ViewInset.

Comment: Implementing the **WidgetsBindingObserver** and in particular the method *didChangeMetrics* may be a solution.  See [article](https://www.didierboelens.com/2018/04/hint-4-ensure-a-textfield-or-textformfield-is-visible-in-the-viewport-when-has-the-focus/)

Comment: This works pretty well, and I'm only really using it because my page layout looks bad when it's scrunched to such a small space so I remove some things.  So I don't think this is a a bad solution for most cases (which pertain to UI).

Comment: This is the only best solution I think.... @RémiRousselet If we know the use cases, using this solution is not at all an issue....

Comment: Bad solution, there is a pure Dart implementation below using WidgetsBindingObserver

Comment: Are you aware that the MediaQuery.of is already subscribed to WidgetsBinding window changes. And it does the same. Would be happy to hear why you think it's bad solution? And WidgetsBindingObserver is also not pure Dart implementation I suppose, it depends on flutter/foundation AFAIK.

Comment: In most cases, when there is a floating keyboard, you would like to treat it as no keyboard, anyway!  Such as in the example given in the qn... with the bottom bar... Why hide the bottom bar when a floating keyboard appears?! ‍♀️ (There may be use cases where you would still like to know, though, I guess. But they gotta be few!)

Comment: Try this   `View.of(context).viewInsets.bottom == 0` this represent Keyboard is hidden

Answer (score 59):

I just created a Flutter plugin to notify about keyboard open and close events. It works both on Android and iOS.

*[keyboard_visibility](https://github.com/adee42/flutter_keyboard_visibility)*

---

```
import 'package:keyboard_visibility/keyboard_visibility.dart';

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  KeyboardVisibilityNotification().addNewListener(
    onChange: (bool visible) {
      print(visible);
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: how are we suppossed to use this plugin? any documentation?

Comment: Just refer to the read me. It is quite simple to use: [link](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/keyboard_visibility#-readme-tab-)

Comment: Sorry I could not find the package on pub.dartlang. This is brilliant, the only way that I found to know if the keyboard is really visible or not (even if your keyboard has a floating keyboard)

Comment: Here the link to the dartlang page: [link](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/keyboard_visibility)

Comment: Plugin is not updated, go to this fork instead: https://github.com/MisterJimson/flutter_keyboard_visibility

Comment: I did like you said and it throws this: The following MissingPluginException was thrown while activating platform stream on channel github.com/adee42/flutter_keyboard_visibility:
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method listen on channel github.com/adee42/flutter_keyboard_visibility)

Comment: This plugin will prevent you doing build for release

Comment: Not working and getting error - MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method listen on channel github.com/adee42/flutter_keyboard_visibility)

Comment: @Kamlesh that's a flag for me to you, it can still be usefull to some and the caps-lock writing is absolutely unnecesseary

Comment: If you are plugin author, take a look at the docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding:
https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.

Comment: use this.  https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_keyboard_visibility.

Answer (score 38):

You can use `WidgetsBinding.instance.window.viewInsets.bottom`. If its value is greater than `0.0` then the keyboard is visible.

```dart
    if(WidgetsBinding.instance.window.viewInsets.bottom > 0.0)
    {
       // Keyboard is visible.
    }
    else
    {
       // Keyboard is not visible.
    }
```

Comment: it return 0.0  even when keyboard is active or open

Comment: (Is that really the expected syntax highlighting? It looks weird. It could be "window" is matching something completely different (in a different programming language).)

Comment: its working perfectly..but its depricated..how to fix?

Comment: @Akshay I used `View.of(context).viewInsets.bottom > 0.0`

Answer (score 28):

In your `StatefulWidget`, create a variable:

```
bool _keyboardVisible = false;
```

Then initialize that variable in the `build` widget;

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _keyboardVisible = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom != 0;
    return child;
}
```

Comment: It's not reliable since viewInsets can be used for other widgets across platforms.

Comment: worked for me. I only need it for a single widget anyway

Answer (score 27):

You can use the **keyboard_visibility** package to do this effectively. I've used it, and it works like a charm.

**To install**

```
dependencies:
  keyboard_visibility: ^0.5.2
```

**Usage**

```
import 'package:keyboard_visibility/keyboard_visibility.dart';

@protected
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  KeyboardVisibilityNotification().addNewListener(
    onChange: (bool visible) {
      print(visible);
    },
  );
}
```

It also supports listeners like show/hide.

[Here is the link](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/keyboard_visibility).

Comment: Your example should be clearer, and show saving the subscription ID, with the accompanying removal call, otherwise you'll get multiple listeners if it's a screen you're using several times. The listener doesn't auto-dispose when the class goes out of scope. 

Beyond that, nice, clean, easy to use. Thanks!

Comment: This plugin will prevent you doing build for release

Comment: I actually used it and I've built for release and even published many times.

Comment: This package does not support NULL SAFETY. This is not useful now.

Comment: use this. https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_keyboard_visibility

Comment: @VipinKrishna's answer works for Flutter 3.7.9, whereas the keyboard_visibility package causes a build error.

Answer (score 13):

This is my solution, which uses [WidgetsBindingObserver](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver-class.html) to observe window size changes, and determine whether the keyboard is hidden based on this.

```
/// My widget state，it can remove the focus to end editing when the keyboard is hidden.
class MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  /// Determine whether the keyboard is hidden.
  Future<bool> get keyboardHidden async {
    // If the embedded value at the bottom of the window is not greater than 0, the keyboard is not displayed.
    final check = () => (WidgetsBinding.instance?.window.viewInsets.bottom ?? 0) <= 0;
    // If the keyboard is displayed, return the result directly.
    if (!check()) return false;
    // If the keyboard is hidden, in order to cope with the misjudgment caused by the keyboard display/hidden animation process, wait for 0.1 seconds and then check again and return the result.
    return await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100), () => check());
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Used to obtain the change of the window size to determine whether the keyboard is hidden.
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // stop Observing the window size changes.
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }
  
  @override
  void didChangeMetrics() {
    // When the window insets changes, the method will be called by the system, where we can judge whether the keyboard is hidden.
    // If the keyboard is hidden, unfocus to end editing.
    keyboardHidden.then((value) => value ? FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus() : null);
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a nice solution, but I don't understand the Future.delayed

Comment: Sometimes the system lags when opening the keyboard? I guess

Answer (score 8):

You can use
[Flutter keyboard visibility plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_keyboard_visibility)

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return KeyboardVisibilityBuilder(
    builder: (context, isKeyboardVisible) {
      return Text(
        'The keyboard is: ${isKeyboardVisible ? 'VISIBLE' : 'NOT VISIBLE'}',
      );
    }
  );
```

Comment: Cleanest solution! thanks

Answer (score 7):

You can use `MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom`. Just look at the documentation below.

> > /// The parts of the display that are completely obscured by system UI,   /// typically by the device's keyboard.   ///   /// When a
> >     mobile device's keyboard is visible `viewInsets.bottom`   ///
> >     corresponds to the top of the keyboard.   ///   /// This value is
> >     independent of the [padding]: both values are   /// measured from the
> >     edges of the [MediaQuery] widget's bounds. The   /// bounds of the top
> >     level MediaQuery created by [WidgetsApp] are the   /// same as the
> >     window (often the mobile device screen) that contains the app.   ///
> >     /// See also:   ///   /// * [MediaQueryData], which provides some
> >     additional detail about this   ///   property and how it differs from
> >     [padding].   final EdgeInsets viewInsets;

Answer (score 2):

With Flutter 2.0 and null safety, I use this package - it has no streams, pure Dart, gives additional information about keyboard height, etc.

*[flutter_keyboard_size 1.0.0+4](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_keyboard_size)*

[image]

Comment: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom already gives you the keyboard height?

Comment: The only solution that works for me, `MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom` didn't.

Answer (score 1):

I used a workaround. I added a focusNode to the input and added a listener to that.

See the implementation here [add focus listener to input](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47970415/6485758).

Comment: Doesn't work if user manually closes the keyboard; input won't lose the focus in that case.

Answer (score -2):

I found an easier solution here:

Put the DesiredBottomWidget in a `Stack()` with a `Positioned(top: somevalue)`, and it will be hidden when the keyboard appears.

Example:

```
Stack(
    "Somewidget()",
    Positioned(
        top: "somevalue",
        child: "DesiredBottomWidget()"),
),
```