# Get keyboard height in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there any way to get an open keyboard's height in Flutter? I'm trying to pad a `bottomSheet` widget by the height of the keyboard while it's open.

Answer (score 49):

Usually [`viewInsets`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/MediaQueryData/viewInsets.html) provides data about any system ui that obscures the flutter ui. To know about the keyboard height, you can just check for the `bottom` property of `viewInsets`, when the keyboard is onscreen, this will hold the height of keyboard else zero.

You can check for the `viewInsets` with `MediaQuery` like:

```
MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom
```

Note: The `bottom` property may have value even if some other system ui obscures the flutter ui from bottom.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, but do you know how to get the keyboard height when the keyboard is not onscreen? I find many native apps can show a container which has the same height of the keyboard in advance when the keyboard is not onscreen. Cheers.

Comment: @sgon00 yes you are right. did you find how to find the height of the keyboard before its open?

Comment: @sgon00 Keyboards can change height (even dynamically) depending on the input type, various keyboard configuration options, and keyboard state (emoji mode, etc.), so I don't think there would be an a priori answer, but even if there is, it would depend upon which `TextField` you were planning to type into.

Comment: Note that you have to use `(MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom + MediaQuery.of(context).viewPadding.bottom)` to get the keyboard height for the rare devices with a hardware keyboard. Those have a minimized software keyboard with just one line (for accessing the clipboard and similar) which adds only to the viewPadding, but not to the viewInsets.

Comment: Reports 0 for me on Android 11+

Answer (score 38):

The `MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets` solution *does not* work for me. It always says `zero` even if keyboard is open. Moreover, looking at the highest-upvoted comment in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48751912/4619958), it is a bad idea to use it as keyboard indicator.

Thus, here is a one-line solution:

```
final viewInsets = EdgeInsets.fromWindowPadding(WidgetsBinding.instance.window.viewInsets,WidgetsBinding.instance.window.devicePixelRatio);
```

Then do whatever you want (e.g. `viewInsets.bottom` is keyboard height) :)

---

**EDIT**: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/FlutterView-class.html is a good source to see how keyboard affects various kinds of padding.

Comment: how can we get keyboard height without opening keyboard. I requirement is related to open a emojis box as overlay of keyboard height which should be same as keyboard height. Any suggestion, please share. Thanks.

Comment: @Kamlesh good question, I also want to know it

Comment: 100% This is the solution to use! Other solutions occasionally said 0 when the keyboard was open for me, weirdly unreliable.

Comment: user it as margin or padding like this  > margin: EdgeInsets.fromWindowPadding(WidgetsBinding.instance!.window.viewInsets,WidgetsBinding.instance!.window.devicePixelRatio),

Comment: Does not work on Android 11 or higher for me.

Answer (score 4):

**If `MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom` shows 0.0, this should work:**

First, go into your `Scaffold` and set this:

```
resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
```

**THEN** you can check the height of the keyboard in this way:

```
MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
```

Answer (score 3):

In case of complicated widget tree `MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom` gives `null` even if the keyboard is open. So, we have to mutate values down the tree.

I made the package that provides all needed info down the tree https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_keyboard_size

Welcome to use and in case you find bugs or want to extend functionality please add the issue https://github.com/awaik/flutter_keyboard_size/issues

[image]

Comment: Why does a complex widget tree not work with the bottom `viewInsets`? How does propagating this information down work, exactly?

Comment: This was checked last time 2 years ago. I think you can check it again - does it work or not? If to be honest, I don't remember already.

Answer (score 3):

This one work for me:
https://pub.dev/packages/keyboard_utils

Sample code from package:
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for me. I always get an incorrect value which leads to an ugly offset.

Answer (score 1):

In my case nothing worked, but I needed screen height without keyboard height and `LayoutBuilder` work perfect.

```
LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (context, constraints) => Container(
    //maxHeight will change depending on your keyboard visible or not
    height:constraints.maxHeight,
  ),
);
```

In theory you can do this

```
LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (context, constraints) {
    double keyboardHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - constrains.maxHeight;
  }
);
```

Comment: what is you have unconstrainted layout, How would you deal with it?

Comment: Just make it constrained. It is meant to be used on higher widget tree levels of the screen. And it is fairly easy to make those constrained with device height.

Answer (score 1):

In case you need to get the keyboard height even when the keyboard is not open, you can use the [flutter_persistent_keyboard_height](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_persistent_keyboard_height) package (note: it was created by me).

First thing you need to do is wrap a widget from children of which you want to get the keyboard height with `PersistentKeyboardHeightProvider`. Wrap your app widget (perhaps `MaterialApp`) if you want to get keyboard height from all widgets.

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Persistent Keyboard Height Example',
      home: const FlutterPersistentKeyboardHeightExample(),
      builder: (context, child) => PersistentKeyboardHeightProvider(
        child: child!,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And after that you can use the `PersistentKeyboardHeight.of(context).keyboardHeight` to get the height.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm! Do note that when using another builder as a child e.g. FutureBuilder, rename the "context" variable to prevent a duplicate

Comment: Code as an image on Stack?!

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own simple widget that will report when keyboard opened and it's size. Widget itself:

```
class KeyboardListenerWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  /// {@macro keyboard_listener_widget}
  const KeyboardListenerWidget({required this.phoneSettingsQyreService, required this.keyboardHeight, super.key});

  final IPhoneSettingsQyreService phoneSettingsQyreService;
  final double keyboardHeight;

  @override
  State<KeyboardListenerWidget> createState() => _KeyboardListenerWidgetState();
}

/// State for widget KeyboardListenerWidget
class _KeyboardListenerWidgetState extends State<KeyboardListenerWidget> {
  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(KeyboardListenerWidget oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget); // Here you report that keyboard state changed
    widget.phoneSettingsQyreService.reportKeyboardOpened(widget.keyboardHeight);
    // Widget configuration changed
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => const SizedBox.shrink();
}
```

And `IPhoneSettingsQyreService` implementation (this service is Singleton, so you create it in the root of your project and pass it to your other widget any way you like):

```
class PhoneSettingsQyreServiceImpl implements IPhoneSettingsQyreService {
  ///...

  /// Keyboard section:
  final _keyboardHeightStreamController = StreamController<double>.broadcast();
  double _keyboardHeight = 0;

  @override
  double get keyboardHeight => _keyboardHeight;

  @override
  Stream<double> get keyboardHeightStream => _keyboardHeightStreamController.stream;

  @override
  void reportKeyboardOpened(double height) {
    _keyboardHeight = height;
    _keyboardHeightStreamController.add(height);
  }

  @override
  void close() {
    _keyboardHeightStreamController.close();
  }
}
```

Just add `KeyboardListenerWidget` to the root of you App like this (`widget.child` is your Material app with navigator or whatever you are using as the root of your app):

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        KeyboardListenerWidget(
          phoneSettingsQyreService: phoneSettingsService,
          keyboardHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
        ),
        widget.child,
        Overlay(key: _overlayKey),
      ],
    );
  }
```

And just listen `keyboardHeightStream` in other widgets to rebuild them if it is needed (or use `StreamBuilder<double>`)

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64473806/2233706) works, but it's deprecated because of [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/EdgeInsets/EdgeInsets.fromWindowPadding.html) and [this](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/window-singleton). Here's an updated solution:

```
final viewInsets = EdgeInsets.fromViewPadding(View.of(context).viewInsets, View.of(context).devicePixelRatio);
```

You can then use the `bottom` property to get the keyboard height. The `vertical` property also works. In a `ListView`, I put the above as the height of a `SizedBox` in last element so that I can scroll to the bottom of a `ListView` while the keyboard is open.