# Flutter When I use a textfield on the page I designed with expanded, everything gets smaller when the keyboard is opened

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-layout, flutter-responsive-layout

When I use a textfield on the page I designed with expanded, everything gets shrink when the keyboard is opened. How can i disable this.

Comment: Set this https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/resizeToAvoidBottomInset.html on your page scaffold to false. Open keyboard will then be above all widgets without resizing,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like not to scroll the page, set `Scaffold`'s   `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` property to `false`. It will avoid any effect that pops up from the keyboard. But it comes with a caveat If your `TextField` is placed within the height of keyboard, whatever user types will not be able to see. Try this if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

you can use singlechildscrollview or listview widget. They will make it scroll.
and you can use MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom for padding or margin. [Get keyboard height in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49269319/get-keyboard-height-in-flutter).