# How do you hide widgets when you are using/tapped into a TextFormField in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I would like to hide a Text widget when a user is currently tapped into a TextFormField to type. And when they aren't using it, I would like for it to be visible again. Only problem is I don't see a way to accomplish this. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to check whether the user is using `TextField` or not is by detecting whether the keyboard is visible or not. For that follow this stack-overflow [post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48750361/flutter-detect-keyboard-open-close) Once you know whether keyboard is visible or not, you can simply update the state(setState()) and decide whether to hide the widget or not. Follow this stack-overflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44489804/show-hide-widgets-in-flutter-programmatically) as a reference to hide and un-hide widgets in flutter.