# Flutter handle Back(Close) button on TextField keyboard

Tags: flutter

I have a textfield that I want to give it some changes when the keyboard closes with the close button at bottom of the phone screen.

Comment: Try wrapping you textfield inside of `WillPopScope` and use `onWillpop` and implement your changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53652566/8112679).

It's a plugin which works on both android & iOS

pub: https://pub.dev/packages/keyboard_visibility

GitHub: https://github.com/adee42/flutter_keyboard_visibility

> ```
> import 'package:keyboard_visibility/keyboard_visibility.dart';
>
> @override 
> void initState() {
>   super.initState();
>
>   KeyboardVisibilityNotification().addNewListener(
>     onChange: (bool visible) {
>       print(visible);
>     },
>   );
> }
> ```