# flutter move floatingActionButton up 50 pixels

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Is it possible to move the `floatingActionButton` up by *50* pixels?

I have a `floatingActionButton` in an App that uses `firebase_admob` and the Ads Banner is overlapping on top of the `floatingActionButton`.

How does one set the `floatingActionButton` to be *50* *pixels* from the bottom of the screen?

From the [documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/FloatingActionButton-class.html) of `floatingActionButton` I can not seem to pick out how to position the button.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Wrap your `FloatingActionButton` inside a Padding and add the size you want:

```
    floatingActionButton: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50.0),
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              child: Icon(Icons.remove),
              onPressed: () => null,
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. This works better, though the display of the keyboard makes the button pad 50 from the displayed keyboard

Comment: you could detect if your keyboard is open , then change the value of the padding to 0 ,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47823767/how-to-listen-to-keyboard-on-screen-flutter

Comment: set resizeToAvoidBottomInset to false in your scaffold and it won't jump when the keyboard gets opened

Answer (score 13):

It's simple.

```
class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(),
      floatingActionButton: Align(
          child: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: null),
          alignment: Alignment(1, 0.7)),
    );
  }
}
```

Use Alignment, as everything is a Widget in Flutter.

Comment: This does help to clear the ads banner, however when the keyboard is displayed, the floatingActionButton jumps to the top. Would prefer it to maintain the bottom padding of 50 pixels

Comment: fixing it ...wait

Comment: hmm it seems to jump up either with padding or using align.Can you share the code or UI?

Comment: The jump happens with both Align and Padidng as suggested by diegoveloper. However the behavior is much better with Padding and as such I will award that as the correct answer. Thank you for the help